# PayPal IPN listener script never stops executing

Tags: php, paypal

I have a PHP web page which uses the creates an invoice and allows the user to pay via PayPal.  The script identifies the IPN listening page via https and that gets called once the user has completed their transaction.  Inside the IPN script that is called, I am updating the invoice status to "paid" and other relevant information upon a successful payment.  The good news is that all functions perfectly.  However, when I add a single payment inside the routine, to a vendor that gets a percent of the sale, the script executes over and over and over and never stops.  The part of the script that seems to be causing the trouble is

```
        case "Completed":
        $vBody = "PayPal has identifed this transaction as Completed.  Your account will be credited.";
        // BEGIN MassPay API Call
        // Create PayPal object.
        $PayPalConfig = array(
            'Sandbox' => $sandbox,
            'APIUsername' => $api_username,
            'APIPassword' => $api_password,
            'APISignature' => $api_signature,
            'PrintHeaders' => $print_headers,
            'LogResults' => $log_results,
            'LogPath' => $log_path,
            );
        $PayPal = new angelleye\PayPal\PayPal($PayPalConfig);
        // Prepare request arrays
        $MPFields = array(
                'emailsubject' => 'Notification of Payment',    // The subject line of the email that PayPal sends when the transaction is completed.  Same for all recipients.  255 char max.
                'currencycode' => 'USD',                                // Three-letter currency code.
                'receivertype' => 'EmailAddress'                        // Indicates how you identify the recipients of payments in this call to MassPay.  Must be EmailAddress or UserID
            );
        // Build MPItems array. 
        $Item1 = array(
                'l_email' => 'recipient@gmail.com',                 // Required.  Email address of recipient.  You must specify either L_EMAIL or L_RECEIVERID but you must not mix the two.
                'l_receiverid' => '',                                   // Required.  ReceiverID of recipient.  Must specify this or email address, but not both.
                'l_amt' => '3.00',                                      // Required.  Payment amount.
                'l_uniqueid' => $Post["invoice"],                       // Transaction-specific ID number for tracking in an accounting system.
                'l_note' => 'Payment per PayPal transaction processing fee.'                                // Custom note for each recipient.
        );
        $MPItems = array($Item1);
        //$MPItems = $Item1;  // ($Item1, $Item2, etc
        $PayPalRequestData = array('MPFields'=>$MPFields, 'MPItems' => $MPItems);
        // Pass data into class for processing with PayPal and load the response array into $PayPalResult
        $PayPalResult = $PayPal->MassPay($PayPalRequestData);
        // END MassPay API Call
        //Update database on succcessful payment
```

The script executes fine and the mass payment to the vendor in the Sandbox works, but it NEVER STOPS.  If I complete a transaction using it, the senders PayPal account would be drained of all funds.  I have read that there may be an issue with the Sandbox, but not sure if that is accurate and there is no way I can put this into production.  Can anyone give me an idea of how to solve or identify the problem?

Comment: you are using a switch but can you copy all of your code please ?

Comment: Here is a link to the code in its entirety

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xPvw9DkFiCD6xwzeMnjIcNQQTCIgbUIA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 break;
```

Or:

```
exit();
```

Which ill make the script stop executing after executing the first time

Comment: I will try that.  But, it appears that the page is being called multiple times by PayPal since I have code to add records for tracking being executed every minute.

Comment: Then simply perform a check to the transaction, first send the data to the database the first time, then check every time if the record exists , if it does you do nothing, otherwise then you execute the script you want and mark it on database. It's just a simple prevention you can do.

Comment: Use the unique id to authenticate every variable in the db

Comment: Problem is if PayPal is continually calling the script it will never stop.  I could check if the payment has already been made and then do nothing, but wont paypal continue to try and execute it anyway?  So if 10 people make a payment on 10 transactions on a day, PayPal will hit the link for those payments every minute for 10 transactions and never stop, at some point the number of hits and records to look up to check the transaction is not new will get burdensome.

Comment: All I really need to figure out is how PayPal knows that the IPN link has been successfullyexecuted and then stops sending it for a specific transaction.